# ArangoDB Java Driver Forwardslash in _id is escaped

Tags: java, arangodb

When querying ArangoDB with an AQL query by means of the Java Driver, the forward slash in the _id property is escaped.

The result is:

```
{"_id":"sed\/CLI_ELE_ALL_400_01.324fd0e4-cf8a-4e39-9889-d1c50ab3594c","_key":"...
```

but I would like this:

```
{"_id":"sed/CLI_ELE_ALL_400_01.324fd0e4-cf8a-4e39-9889-d1c50ab3594c","_key":"...
```

code snippet:

```
  String query = "for node in nodes return node"

  try {

        ArangoCursor<String> cursor = driver.query(query, null, null, String.class);

        if (cursor.hasNext()) {
            data = cursor.next();
            System.out.println(data));
        }

    } catch (ArangoDBException ex) {}

    return data;
```

Is there some way to circumvent this without needing to regex replace everything??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the parameter `type` in your query() call to `String`, this leads the java-driver to parse the result into the Json format. In Json it is correct that `/` and other characters are escaped. Every Json parser should be able to deal with it.

The java-driver already supports parsing the result into a POJO, `Map<String, Object>` or into the utility class `BaseDocument` without the detour over Json. You can find some examples for this [here](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb-java-driver/blob/master/src/test/java/com/arangodb/example/document/GetDocumentExample.java).